# Where can I find a single example expressed in Ivy, Maven, Gant, and Gradle?

Tags: maven-2, ant, ivy, gradle, gant

I'd like to find a simple, non-trivial Java project that is expressed in terms of Ant + Ivy, Maven, Gant, and Gradle. I'm not interested in each tool's varied sample demos.

Where can I find such an example, for reference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't find one, so I'm working on such an example. The [project is hosted here on GitHub](http://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_build_tools), and is freely available without an account.

The first 'simple' example uses a Java POJO, a Hibernate mapping file, and an integration test. It is expressed in Ant, Ant + Ivy, Maven, Gant, and Gradle. Though modest, the integration test passes in each case.

Comment: Thank you for the effort. If I may comment (and please let me know if there's a better forum), but the Gradle one doesn't look like Gradle.

Is there a reason you're not using the java plugin for Gradle, and defining dependencies? It just feels like an Ant script.

Comment: re: forum. If you have an account on GitHub, you can probably message me or possibly open an issue. If not, here is fine with me.

I agree that the current example isn't done in a way that is idiomatic to Gradle. It is a work in progress. I hope to update the site soon with a couple of different styles of Gradle. thanks for the note

Comment: FWIW, there is a new Gradle example that uses the Java plugin. I encourage readers to file further issues on GitHub or send me an email (see my blog for contact info). Feedback is welcome.